# Oracle sqlldr ORA-28009:connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I try to run from DOS `sqlldr` with `SYS/PASS@`

```
sqlldr.exe 'sys/PASS@orcl' control="D:/test/control_file.dat" log="D:/test/log.log"
```

And got this error

> Oracle sqlldr ORA-28009:connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER

Is anyone can tell me to specify `SYSDBA` or `SYSOPER` in command line above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `AS SYSDBA` to your connection string. Try this:

```
sqlldr.exe 'sys/PASS@orcl AS SYSDBA' control="D:/test/control_file.dat" log="D:/test/log.log"
```

P.S.

**NOTE** from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm):

> This example shows the entire connect string enclosed in quotation marks and backslashes. This is because the string, AS SYSDBA, contains a blank, a situation for which most operating systems require that the entire connect string be placed in quotation marks or marked as a literal by some method. Some operating systems also require that quotation marks on the command line be preceded by an escape character. In this example, backslashes are used as the escape character. If the backslashes were not present, the command line parser that SQL*Loader uses would not understand the quotation marks and would remove them.
> See your Oracle operating system-specific documentation for information about special and reserved characters on your system.